# Add zoom levels to the build of a mbtile from a TIFF file

Tags: raster, gdal, gdal-translate, mbtiles

I have build a raster file (.tif) using GDAL, but I want to set different zoom levels for it but when running:

```
gdal_translate -of MBTiles -co "ZOOM_LEVEL_STRATEGY=AUTO" -co "TILE_FORMAT=PNG"  inpur.mbtiles output.mbtiles

gdal_translate -of MBTiles  -co ZOOM_LEVEL=6 -co "TILE_FORMAT="PNG" input.tif output.mbtiles
```

Also tried:

```
gdal_translate -of MBTiles -co "TILE_FORMAT=PNG" -co ZLEVEL=6-16 input.tif output.mbtiles
```

But results coming form second command was with  a warning (Warning 6: driver MBTiles does not support creation option ZOOM_LEVEL) against what I could understood in the [MBTILES gdal site](https://gdal.org/drivers/raster/mbtiles.html#creation-options)

The third command generates exactly the same zoom levels than the two previous commands.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The GDAL MBTiles driver writes always a MBTiles file that has only one zoom level. More lower zoom levels can be created afterwards with gdaladdo as documented in https://gdal.org/drivers/raster/mbtiles.html#overviews-raster.

The MBTiles driver doesn't have a ZOOM_LEVEL creation option that you tried to use. For rasters the only creation option that affects zoom levels is ZOOM_LEVEL_STRATEGY that can have an effect of +1 or -1 on the base zoom level. With all alternatives the pixel size in MBTiles is close to the pixel size of the source data. The MBTiles driver writes always just one zoom level but lower zoom levels can be added later.

> **ZOOM_LEVEL_STRATEGY=[AUTO/LOWER/UPPER]**:
>
> Defaults to AUTO. Strategy to determine zoom level. LOWER will select
> the zoom level immediately below the theoretical computed non-integral
> zoom level, leading to subsampling. On the contrary, UPPER will select
> the immediately above zoom level, leading to oversampling. Defaults to
> AUTO which selects the closest zoom level.

What was the zoom level that gdal_translate created can be checked with gdalinfo. The metadata section shows for example:

```
  minzoom=17
  maxzoom=17
```

The overviews can be added afterwards with the gdaladdo utility as documented in https://gdal.org/drivers/raster/mbtiles.html#overviews-raster

> **Overviews (raster)**
>
> gdaladdo / BuildOverviews() can be used to compute overviews. Only
> power-of-two overview factors (2,4,8,16,...) are supported.

Example about creating three additional zoom levels with gdaladdo:

```
gdaladdo output.mbtiles 2 4 8
```

What is interesting is that there seems to be some kind of bug in gdalinfo. It shows now in the metadata section

```
  maxzoom=17
  minzoom=11
```

and similarly six overview levels in the band descriptions

```
Overviews: 5569x5577, 2785x2788, 1392x1394, 696x697, 348x349, 174x174
```

However, the instruction to create only 3 new zoom levels (16, 15, and 14) is actually honoured. That can be checked with ogrinfo because the MBTiles file is a normal SQLite database.

```
ogrinfo SQLite:output.mbtiles -sql "SELECT min(zoom_level) as min, max(zoom_level) as max from tiles" output.mbtiles
...
OGRFeature(SELECT):0
  min (Integer) = 14
  max (Integer) = 17
```

Comment: one of the best answer i had. Thanks